# Data binding VB.NET Model using while loop

Tags: vb.net

NET 
Trying to binding data into model from Stored Procs using while loop; please advice how to make work my following code; that is converted using Telerik Converter.

```
 Try
            Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read()
                login.Add(New LoginDetails() With { _
                    Name = reader("EmployessFullName").ToString(), _
                    Win_UserName = reader("win_username").ToString() _
                })
                End While
            End Using
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

My actual C# Code is bellow

```
 try
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        login.Add(new LoginDetails()
                        {
                            Name = reader["EmployessFullName"].ToString(),
                            Win_UserName = reader["win_username"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: I see where you are updating the values of the data source (presumably the login instance), but I don't see any code that updates the Data Source on an underlying control. Ex = MyGrid.DataSource = login

Comment: this is I am trying to do
 public IEnumerable<LoginDetails> GetUserLoginDetails(string userName, string  password)
        {
            List<LoginDetails> login = new List<LoginDetails>(); // Do something 
return login;
}

Comment: Error coming from because login.Add(New LoginDetails() With { _
                    Name = reader("EmployessFullName").ToString(), _ is not valid syntax

Comment: Remove underscore

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments you should change your code to match the syntax with what is done in the Telerik control (you forgot the With Keyword):

```
login.Add(new LoginDetails()
With
{
    Name = reader["EmployessFullName"].ToString(),
    Win_UserName = reader["win_username"].ToString()
});
```

Or by instantiating the LoginDetails into its own variable:

```
LoginDetails loginDetails = new LoginDetails();

loginDetails.Name = reader["EmployessFullName"].ToString()
loginDetails.Win_UserName = reader["win_username"].ToString()

login.Add(loginDetails);
```

Comment: hi #NoAlias my C# code is correct; but I want to convert them into VB

Comment: Typically you won't get those types of questions answered.  Check out this link:  http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: I already used Telerik Converter to Convert my C# code to VB; and that produced wired code;

Comment: # NoAlias your both solutions are in C#;